# Return all the children of a DOM element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How to get all the children from a DOM element and not only the immediate children and return them using JavaScript?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean saying  "not only the immediate children" ?

Comment: The correct term for "children and not only the immediate children" is **descendants**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to get all the descendants of a DOM element, you may use `*` in CSS-selectors:

```
#elem *
.className *
div *
```

For example, you can extract all descendants of `elem` element using vanilla JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#elem *')
```

or jQuery

```
$('#elem *')
```

**Demo:** (result appears in console)

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#elem *'), function(x) {
  console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<div id="notAnElem">
  <a></a>
  <i></i>
</div>

<div id="elem">
  <div>
    <a></a>
  </div>
  <i></i>
</div>

All descendants of `elem` should appear in console
```

Comment: This will not return text nodes, in case the OP wanted them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

If the entire body -

```
var c = document.body.childNodes;
```

If a certain DIV -

```
var c = document.getElementById("myDIV").childNodes
```

The above will also include text nodes and comments nodes

And if you need only element nodes, use this -

```
var c = document.body.children;
```

**Note:** All the above variable are collection of elements that can be later iterated using for loop with 'c.length' as the limit.